# Is there way to watch one ZNode in two process in zookeeper?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-zookeeper

I have `/math` is the root node(have been set Watcher on this on in both processes). I create child node `math/exam01` in process A, and create child node `math/exam02` in process B(after create child `math/exam01`). I expect event thread will be trigger by Watcher in process A. But nothing happen, can explain me what happen with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to follow your question:

In process A you setup a watch on an existing znode `/math`. This watch is to observe events relevant to children znodes of `/math` so you should set them up with the following command:

`[PROCESS A]: ls -w /math`

Then, you create a child node using the client from process A for the `/math/exam01` path, using the following command:

`[PROCESS A]: create /math/exam01`

You just created a subnode of `/math` so you triggered the event Watch.

Then you use the client from process B to create a new child node of `/math` at `/math/exam02`. This operation will not trigger any Watch event in process A because the triggers are **One-time**. Should you require an event to be sent, after the frist event trigger in process A, you should re-set the watch for `/math`.

More information on ZooKeeper watches [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches).